# Centered grid view

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

I'm having pretty simple but yet complex issue that I can't resolve.

I have a list of div html elements (cards) that I want to display into Grid view.
By grid view I mean if there are 10 and current width is good for 4 in a row it would be 4-4-2, but the last 2 won't be centered, but start from the beginning of the row (each under the same element from the row above).
Example:

X X X X

X X X X

X X

This can be solved easy with display:grid or flex and flex-start direction. But Also I want this container where all the cards are displayed to be in the center of the screen + the container width to be exactly as the children elements combined widths in first row.
The final result should be grid system, centered exactly in the middle horizontally.
Currently looks like this:
[image]

The issues I have are:

- the container is always with more width than the elements inside, and when it is centered, the grid still doesn't look centered, but little to the left. If the container width is somehow same width as the 3 elements inside in this case on this resolution, then it would be centered with some div wrapper around him or some other trick. I don't want to put static widths as I want this to work on all resolutions. To be responsive
- Second issue is that some cards have different height, so I need all cards to have same height as the highest one in the row.

Comment: Post the code for your demo so that people can show you how to modify it. :-)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with posting code in a way that enables us to run it.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue - 2**
By giving `height: auto` to the child div issue can be solved.

`.childDiv {border:1px solid black; margin: 10px; width:150px; height:auto; padding: 10px;}`

[ChildDiv will look like this with huge texts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Li5Ku.png)

**Issue - 1**

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  padding:10px;
  width: 95%;
  margin: -5px;
  justify-content:space-between;
  height: 500px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border:1px solid black;
  overflow: auto;
}

.parent: after {
  content: '';
  flex: auto;
  flex-gap: 10px;
 }

.childDiv {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px 5px;
  width:200px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

This code can solve the issue in some static resolutions
```

[Image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRuHs.png)